# Barren plateaus in multi-qubit system

Tags: quantum-state

I'm looking on pennylane's tutorial

https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_barren_plateaus.html

In this link, to illustrate barren plateaus, author used example circuit and barren plateau plots. However, I'm curious why the plot (the right figure) only includes the $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ (Is the plateau only  example to show the barren pleateaus or $\theta_3$ and $\theta_4$ are not related with it. Moreover, if the right figure is just an example and $\theta_3$ and $\theta_4$ are related with barren plateaus, Is there any way to plot barren plateaus of multi-qubit system? not only the 2qubit system.

Answer (score 1):

Plotting only two parameters at once is a human limitation: we can only visualise three dimensions at most (2 parameters + the energy values).

The authors claim that they took a slice, and correctly so. In principle, you can take another slice of any other combination of two out of the four parameters to visualise.

Now as to your final question: yes, there are ways to plot more than 3 dimensions in a figure but you will mostly loose the intuitive 3D nature of the plot given in your link. The phrase you want to Google is "Visualization of Multi-dimensional Data"